# Cypress: Upload file exent execution

Tags: file-upload, cypress

I have such an input file tag:

```
                      <input type="file" 
                         #fileInput formControlName="browseDocument"
                         id="uploadFile"
                         (change)="uploadFileEvt($event)"
                         name="uploadFile"
                         accept=".pdf,.xml"
                  />
```

I want to test the upload file, but I need that `uploadFileEvt` function will be executed.

How could I cause it to happen in the test?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to use `.trigger('change')` after the `.attachFile()` or `.selectFile()`,

```js
cy.get('input[type=file]')
  .selectFile({...})
  .trigger('change')
```